# How do I write a command that tests for shears?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I recently watched a video of how to use command blocks, and in it this guy showed that you cannot enter a certain place without shears. When he got shears he could walk through.

I know how to do `/say`, but I don't know how to require shears to walk in a certain block. What do I need to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mark or modify a player with a specific item in their inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191594/is-it-possible-to-mark-or-modify-a-player-with-a-specific-item-in-their-inventor)

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just use the updated `/clear` command. Here's an example of a setup to open an iron door:

```
#1 /setblock <x> <y> <z> redstone_block 0 destroy
#2 /clear @a[r=10] <item id> 0 0 {display:{Name:"<custom item name>"}}
```

Here's the setup of the command blocks:

```
[] = iron door
{} = comparator
() = redstone_block
#1 = command block 1
#2 = command block 2

#1()#2{}[]
```

To explain exactly how this works, I'll go command by command. The first command block sets up a constant redstone loop, which will be constantly activating command block two. Command block two is testfor the item in the player's hand if the player is within a radius of ten blocks. Then command block two outputs a redstone signal which activates the iron door. Also, here are a few commands you might want to run in order to not lag your world:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
/gamerule doTileDrops false
```

Lastly you **must** play in the latest **snapshot** of minecraft for this to correctly work. I hope this helps!