# Is there a way to give a player a score if they are holding a certain item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have been making a special snowball that when you throw it, it will deal damage to mobs.  It does this with an `/effect @e[r=1]` command but in survival, it will kill the player. I want to give a score to the player holding the snowball. Currently, I use a testfor command to test if the player would have the snowball which means when he or she throws it there is an entity data command which gives the snowball a tag which a execute command executes an effect tag. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I answered your question but you might want to look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/318351/186522), [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/319206/186522), and [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/317722/186522) as they deal in targeting projectiles.  They may help you achieve your goal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to mark or modify a player with a specific item in their inventory](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191594/is-it-possible-to-mark-or-modify-a-player-with-a-specific-item-in-their-inventor)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good place to use [scoreboard tags](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Tags) as opposed to a [scoreboard objective](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Objectives).  This will allow you to tag any player holding a snowball and use that tag to target them in a command without having to setup an objective to track a score.

---

Use 2 command blocks in a chain. The first command block removes the tag from all players.  The second command block tags any player holding a snowball.  These command blocks have to remain loaded.  I recommend putting them in the [spawn chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn_chunk).  I recommend silencing command block output to prevent chat spam for op's. Use command:

```
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

The first command block is <kbd>Repeat</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a remove Holding
```

The second command block is <kbd>Chain</kbd><kbd>Unconditional</kbd><kbd>Always Active</kbd> with command:

```
scoreboard players tag @a add Holding {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:snowball"}}
```

Now you can use this tag within the [target selector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Target_selectors) to exclude the players who are currently holding a snowball.  In your case possibly:

```
/effect @e[r=1,tag=!Holding]
```

---

If you still want to give a player a score instead of a tag, it would be the same solution as above except the commands would be:

```
scoreboard players set @a Holding 0
```

And:

```
scoreboard players set @a Holding 1 {SelectedItem:{id:"minecraft:snowball"}}
```

Also to note, if the snowball is custom named or special in some other way, you can probably use parts of the [data tag](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Data_tags) portion of your current testfor command in the data tag of the 2nd command block command.